# C - Use pointers to creat more Efficient loop to go through the alphabet

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, for-loop

I need to loop through the_message_array and then print a letter of the alphabet when it is equivalent to a number in the_alphabet_array. The_alphabet_array's elements are matched with the alphabet, i.e., the_alphabet_array[0] matches a, the_alphabet_array[1] matches b, and so on. I cannot use ascii, the letters point to specific numbers in the_alphabet_array. If there is another simpler way to do this, rather than moving through 26 if statements, I would very much appreciate the help.
Here is the alphabet array:

```
2, 0, 15, 14, 24, 6, 19, 9, 25, 13, 7, 5, 21, 10, 12, 11, 4, 22, 23, 20, 17, 8, 18, 3, 1, 16
```

Here is the message array:

```
15 ,12,10,19,22,2,20,17,5 ,2,20,25 ,12 ,10 ,23
```

So 'a' points to 2 in the alphabet array, 'b' points to 0, etc. When 2 occurs in the message array, 'a' is printed.

```
int the_letter_char[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z'};
int message_equals_cipher = 0;

    for(message_equals_cipher; message_equals_cipher < 15; message_equals_cipher++){
            if(the_message_array[message_equals_cipher] == the_alphabet_array[0]){
                    printf("%c", the_letter_char[0]);
             }
             if(the_message_array[message_equals_cipher] == the_alphabet_array[1]){
                    printf("%c", the_letter_char[1]);
             }
             if(the_message_array[message_equals_cipher] == the_alphabet_array[2]){
                    printf("%c", the_letter_char[2]);
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing to do would be to simply if the ASCII value of the character is within the correct bounds, like this:

```
char c = the_message_array[message_equals_cipher];
if (c > 63 && c < 91) || (c > 96 && c < 123) {
  printf("%c", c);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, but I can't use ascii values. I edited my question and code for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need another array eg new_alphabet:

```
char new_alphabet[26];
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    new_alphabet[ the_alphabet_array[i] ] = the_letter_char[i];
}
```

and then:

```
for(message_equals_cipher; message_equals_cipher < 15; message_equals_cipher++){
    printf("%c", new_alphabet[ the_message_array[message_equals_cipher] ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct answer is to use a loop inside your loop.

```
int message_equals_cipher = 0;
for (message_equals_cipher; message_equals_cipher < 15; message_equals_cipher++)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(the_alphabet_array) ; i += 1)
        {
        if (the_message_array[message_equals_cipher] ==  the_alphabet_array[i])
            {
            printf("%c", the_letter_char[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that this means traversing the entire `the_alphabet_array` for each letter in the_message_array.  It is not the most efficient algorithm, but is equivalent to and better than writing out each condition manually in the code.  (It is *O(n*m)*; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

For a faster algorithm to check that a character is in a certain range, and if you only need to handle ASCII characters, see jwosty's answer using the numeric code of each character.  (He also identifies both upper and lower case letters)

Note that C is not careful in its handling of integers versus characters.  Sometimes you can use this to your advantage, but other times you need to be extra careful that you don't mix them unintentionally.